# PHP-CLI script doesn't know $_SERVER when called by Apache?

Tags: undefined, php, superglobals

here's a weird one:

I have a PHP-CLI script that runs just fine when called from a shell.

But when I have apache execute it via `system()` it seems to forget about all the superglobals (or at least `$_SERVER`) (they are `1`/`true`).

Any ideas on where that's coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `readline` extension was the badguy.

Deactivated it and it works.